# Two network adapters for a machine to double the transfer speed

Tags: networking, load-balancing, bandwidth, local-area-network, adapter

i am new to this. In my scenario, i have a desktop pc running windows 7 and planning to set up a local web server using xampp for big file transfer in the lab. The problem is that,there are 80 machines in lab but my connection to the router(100mbps router) is just 100mbps ie, 12.x MB. when there is a big file transfer, each node will only get a speed of around 150KB... which takes too much time if the files is big enough..

is it possible to have 2 lan cards connected to same router so my connection the router is overall 200 mbps and each node will get 300KB... is there is any possible method???

Comment: I don't believe so - your machine will choose one of the two cards / local IPs to communicate through. I would suggest upgrading the router and network card on your machine to 1GBPS and make sure everything is performed over wired connection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would depend on your switch. Professional switches offer LACP support (802.3ad link aggregation). With LACP you can bond multiple cables and/or NICs together. This way you have more speed (although it will not split up single flows - but in your case you have atleast 80 flows).

If your switch does not support LACP, you can have different IP-adresses across the NICs, and use (for example) round-robin DNS to balance traffic.

Comment: In second method , which nic will used by os to communicate..will it choose one as active or both at a time

Comment: In the second example, both NICs will be active but with different IP addresses. The DNS will balance requests across multiple IPs.